# Multi site - Licensing query?

Tags: expresso-store, multi-site-manager, licensing

Looking to build multiple sites with EE. How many licenses would have to be purchased as require integration with Expresso Ecommerce. Do I have to get 3 separate licenses or just 1 license and run multiple sites sitting on the same server?

Thanks,

Huzza

Answer (score 3):

Licensing questions are best addressed by the respective software developer.

For ExpressionEngine, a MSM license initially covers 3 sites, all of which must be the same company, i.e. you can not use the sites in a MSM installation for multiple clients. It is best to email EllisLab if you have any questions about the license before making a purchase.

As for Expresso Store, you'll need to read the license to determine if it's per site or per installation and how the applies to MSM. Again, if there are things you're not clear on, it's always best to contact the developer.

Comment: To clarify, an MSM licence also requires a SINGLE EE licence which will allow you to run up to 3 sites. Further licences can then be purchased from Ellis Labs.

Answer (score 2):

An Expresso Store license is essentially tied to your EE license. So if you can legally use one EE license for your sites, then you can also use a single Store license as well.

You can use Store with EE's multi-site manager (MSM) to run multiple online stores from the same installation.

As others have stated, MSM can only be used for multiple properties run by the same company and hosted together. It can't be used to run various client sites from a single installation. It also can't be used to install multiple completely separate sites on the same server (or different servers).

Expresso Stores license allows you to run multiple sites if you are